# How to add query parameters in Zoom API (GET) request?

Tags: api, postman, query-string, zoom-sdk

I'm trying to get all meeting recordings saved in the cloud in a date range using using the following API:

https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/cloud-recording/recordingslist

This is the API response I'm getting in postman.

```
{
"from": "2021-06-01",
"to": "2021-06-02",
"page_count": 1,
"page_size": 30,
"total_records": 1,
"next_page_token": "",
"meetings": [
    {
        
        
        "topic": "Meeting Room",
        "type": 4,
        "start_time": "2021-06-02T10:00:47Z",
        "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta",
        "duration": 0,
        "total_size": 0,
        "recording_count": 0,
        "recording_files": [
            {
                "recording_start": "2021-06-02T10:02:39Z",
                "recording_end": "2021-06-02T10:05:29Z",
                "file_type": "MP4",
                "file_extension": "MP4",
                "file_size": 3181252,
                "status": "completed",
                "recording_type": "shared_screen_with_speaker_view"
            },
            {
                "recording_start": "2021-06-02T10:02:39Z",
                "recording_end": "2021-06-02T10:05:29Z",
                "file_type": "M4A",
                "file_extension": "M4A",
                "file_size": 2694678,
                "status": "completed",
                "recording_type": "audio_only"
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

I am unable to get all the recordings of the desired time range. The "from" and "to" parameters are not changing even after trying the below query.

`https://api.zoom.us/v2//users/me/recordings?from="2020-07-01"&to="2021-06-01"`

Answer (score 0):

In postman use this API

```
https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/{{user id}}/recordings?from=2022-01-01&meeting_id={{meeting id}}
```

Thanks to @ajaidanial